# Warning Message :The condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r

I am trying evaluate the scores  for different algorithms used to make certain predictions. I have used the `scoring_model` as function

```
scoring_model <- function(observed, predicted) {

 if (observed < predicted) 
    score <- ((exp(-(observed - predicted)/10)) -1 )

   else if(observed > predicted) 
    score <- ((exp((observed - predicted)/13)) -1 )

  else score <- 0

  metrics_score <- c("Score" = score)

  return(metrics_score)
}
```

after running this code , i am getting a error as

```
##Warning message:

##In if (observed < predicted) score <- ((exp(-(observed - predicted)/10)) -  :
##the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: How did you run your function? What `observed` and `predicted` did you use?

Comment: Observed and Predicted variables have numerical values